# Thread extracting substring from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nsstring, nsthread

I'm doing some work using the RedPark Serial Cable for iOS. This is a cable that allows serial communication between an iOS device and another device like a microcontroller.

There is a method that comes with the RedPark SDK that reads the bytes available on the Serial Line. This method is called anytime the cable receives informatino.

```
(void)readDataBytes(UInt32 bytes) {
   NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWith...bytes];
   NSString *editedString = [self extractSubStringMethod:s];
   [myArray addObject:editedString];
}
```

The microcontroller  is sending the information in the following format

```
<msg>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</msg>
```

I want to be able to extract the x's from the message (which is taken in as an NSString). At the moment I'm using NSRange to extract everything after position 4 (the first x) and before the final "< /msg>" I'm not convinced it works and was wondering is there any other ideas?

Finally, I have an NSThread which is running alongside this, I have the messages being added to an NSMutableArray. So what I want is, the NSThread to be manipulating/displaying the message information when there is a message received from the cable. I have something like the following

```
//Thread method, 
while([myArray count] > 0) //Don't believe this is neccesary but its in anyway
{
  for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++){
    NSString *string = [myArray objectAt(i)];
    [self displayString:string];
    [myArray removeObjectAt(i);
    }
}
```

I believe it's crashing around the above... [self displayString:string] just sets the value of a label, something like

```
-(void)displayString(NSString *string) {
 label.text = [string charAt(1)];
}
```

The code above is just from memory as I've left my Mac at home and I'm in work. 
Any suggestions/help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
while([myArray count] > 0) //Don't believe this is neccesary but its in anyway
{
  for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++){
    NSString *string = [myArray objectAt(i)];
    [self displayString:string];
    [myArray removeObjectAt(i);
    }
}
```

try like this:

```
while ([myArray count] > 0)
{
    [self displayString: myArray[0]];        
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To address your first concern, `[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, string.length - 6)]` should be sufficient and should work without any issues. You could use an `NSRegularExpression` to match the content inside the tags, but that would be overkill for such a simple task (and would have a performance hit).

Secondly, UIKit methods must only be called from the main thread (see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW1)):

> **Note**: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from `UIResponder` or that involve manipulating your application’s user interface in any way.

You appear to be setting the text of a label in a different thread. This is what is causing the crash. You need to call your `displayString:` method like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayString:) withObject:string waitUntilDone:YES];
```

This will execute the method on the main thread instead of on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must not update UI on secondary thread.
2. Mutable classes are not thread safe.

   while([myArray count]){
   NSString *string = [myArray objectAt(0)];
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayString:) withObject:string waitUntilDone:NO];
   [myArray removeObjectAt(0);
   }